# Find Button element by text

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox, selenium-webdriver

```
<button aria-label="Connect with ABC" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1510="1510">Connect</button>

<button aria-label="Connect with DEF" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1467="1467">Invite Sent !</button>
```

I am trying to find button With text "Connect" using

```
connect_buttons = firefox.find_elements_by_link_text ('Connect')
```

But firefox is not able to find button.

Even i have tried using following mode but

```
firefox.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Connect')]")
# Not accurate results

firefox.find_elements_by_css_selector('.search-result__actions--primary.button-secondary-medium.m5'); 
# return all button with same css even which doesn't have text "Connect".
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks Vadim for formatting my question. :)

Comment: Is the element inside an IFRAME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `relative xpath`. Try below code and it should work if your remaining code is correct

```
.//*[@class='search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5']//*[text()='Connect']
```

Comment: I tried using relative xpath but not able to return result.